# How to adjust submenu height and width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to adjust the width and height of menu>sub menu in the website `http://www.cooltvforum.com/`.

Some long sub menu items are not fit in height, it doesn't look good. I want to fix this.

Here is the css code:

**Sub menu code**

```
#menu3 li ul {background: #292929;border: solid #000;border-width: 0;height: auto;left:-999em;margin-left: -65px;position: absolute;width: 344px;z-index: 9999;}
```

**A href visited link code**

```
#menu3 li li a, #menu3 li li a:link, #menu3 li li a:visited {color: #fff;float: none;margin: 0;padding: 9px 7px;width: 158px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `height:auto` to `#menu3 li li, #menu3 li li li` and its `hover` style

[image]

Comment: Sowmya - I already tried to do that , it doesn't work, . any other idea?

Comment: @user1267173 it works for me. Check the screenshot attached in the answer

Answer (score 0):

using min-height for li height, solve problem perhaps